# How do I redirect a subdomain to a subfolder, while also redirecting the site from http to https?

Tags: nginx

I first did the http -> https redirect. This is what I used:

```
if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}
if ($host != "www.example.com") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri permanent;
}
```

But I also need to redirect apples.example.com to https://example.com/fruits/apples/

How do I do that while also still doing the https redirects? Im able to do one or the other but cant figure out how to do both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out. This is what I ended up with:

```
if ($host = "apples.example.com") {
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com/fruit/apples$request_uri permanent;
}

if ($scheme != "https") {
    rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}
```

Comment: Using separate server block would be more simple and efficient